# Parse SGML using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, data-processing, sgmlreader

Below is the sample content :-

```
<WKEXT-META-ATTRS>
<WKEXT-META-ATTR NAME="uri" VALUE="http://sample.com/ceres/wk-us/Concept/i8148" DATA-TYPE="OTHER"></WKEXT-META-ATTR></WKEXT-META-ATTRS></WKEXT-META-OBJECT>
<WKEXT-META-OBJECT NAME="UNIONREPINFO" ID="ext-met-0005" PUBLISHER-URI="http://wk-us.com/meta/publishers/#CCH">
<WKEXT-META-ATTRS>
<WKEXT-META-ATTR NAME="UnionRep" VALUE="Jim Gookins" DATA-TYPE="OTHER"></WKEXT-META-ATTR></WKEXT-META-ATTRS></WKEXT-META-OBJECT>
<WKEXT-META-OBJECT NAME="TOPICALSUBJECTINFO" ID="ext-met-0006" PUBLISHER-URI="http://sample.com/meta/publishers/#CCH">
<WKEXT-META-ATTRS>
<WKEXT-META-ATTR NAME="uri" VALUE="http://sample.com/ceres/sample/Concept/i8173" DATA-TYPE="OTHER"></WKEXT-META-ATTR></WKEXT-META-ATTRS></WKEXT-META-OBJECT>
<WKEXT-META-OBJECT NAME="TOPICALSUBJECTINFO" ID="ext-met-0007" PUBLISHER-URI="http:/sample/meta/publishers/#CCH">
```

I want to extract the VALUE of uri -- "http://sample.com/ceres/wk-us/Concept/i8141

I am currently trying out with below code:-

```
with open ("sample.sgm","r")as f:
    contents =f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
    s = soup.find('wkext-meta-attr').attrs
    #for a in s:
    #    t = a.attrs
    #    for key,value in t.items():
    #        alias_text.append(t['normval'])
    #print(alias_text)
    #df = DataFrame(alias_text, columns=['arbitratorname'])
    #s_topic=soup.find('WKEXT-META-ATTRS'=
    print(s)
```

I am not able to figure out how to obtain the exact value .
Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: What is the issue with the code?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe i am not able to get the value with this code , its not working for this requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the value of each `wkext-meta-attr`, You can use the`.findAll() method and then loop through each element. Check whether the below code fulfills your task:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ("sample.sgm","r")as f:
    contents =f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
    meta_attrs = soup.findAll('wkext-meta-attr')
    
for meta_attr in meta_attrs:
    print(meta_attr['value'])
```

Comment: I tried this way too , its giving me a blank list . any idea what could be the issue

Comment: Did you change the parser into `html.parser`?

Comment: i did , but still giving a blank list

Comment: I used the sample you posted in your question to check my code and it worked.

Comment: i am passing the SGML file can that be the issue , that html parser is not working on sgml ?

Comment: Can you share a link to the SGML file?